# Chrome View Value Return Value of Function (Not Stored in a Variable)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Using Google Chrome, how can I view a function's  return value when it is not stored in a variable?

For example, in the following code

```
if (d.jStorage.get("tmpdatas").step == d.jStorage.get("constraints").nb_max_questions) {
    return true
}
```

How am I able to see the value of `d.jStorage.get("constraints").nb_max_questions)` in Google Chrome's Debug Tools?

Comment: I just paused that line in the debugger, and pasted d.jStorage.get("constraints").nb_max_questions into the console and that worked.

Comment: Simply select that part of code and hover the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could copy the expression and paste it in the console, which will print the return value. However, a downside of this approach is that the function will be called twice, once by the application code and once by the code you pasted in the console.

You can also step into the `get` function, step through it, and then look for the return value in the Scope pane.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to reference that value? If, for instance, I don't want to have a break-point but rather a log-point...

Comment: Sometimes it is greyed out and there is no way to inspect the return value.